# Ghostscript pdf2jpg - colours wrong?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I'm using the Ghostscript API from c#, to convert multipage PDF's to jpgs.

My issue is with colour conversion.

When I open the Source PDF in photoshop, and export to jpeg, each colour in each jpeg matches the colours of the original PDF perfectly.

However, when I run the process through Ghostscript, the colour come out as different shades than the original. eg:

Original PDF colour: #8DBB3F;
Photoshop pdf to jpg colour: #8DBB3F;
Ghostscript pdf2jpg colour: #7DEE00;

This happens with all colours - all slightly to massively different shades.

These are the arguements passed to ghostscipt:

"pdf2jpg -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=jpeg -r150 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dMaxStripSize=8192 -sOutputFile=myfile-%d.jpg

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

try "-dUseCIEColor"

Answer (score 1):

Add `-dUseCIEColor` (as sovo said) plus try adding `-dJPEGQ=95` to set JPEG quality to 95%.

Also, you may want to try `-sDEVICE=jpegcmyk` to make the JPEG use the CMYK color space.

*(`-sDEVICE=jpeg` uses RGB colors. If your PDF had used CMYK, conversion to RGB will probably cause more color deviations, especially in the absence of ICC profile usage.)*

Answer (score 0):

-dUseCIEColor worked for me, BUT then I tried using an updated DLL version, and that solved the issue without passing in the new flag, and it also resolved my font rendering issue with an embedded font. I replaced by older DLL with the version 9.16. I also was able to leave my jpeg quality at 100.

Answer (score 0):

Try DPI parameter value 300+ (-r300) in ghostscript